# How to make an Asp.Net core web app that supports multiple providers?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core

I'm in the process of designing an application and I've some challenges: The app that we will make will be deployed by our customers in very various places. Based of its pre

Some will deploy it on Azure, some will deploy it on their own servers, ...
The same applies for the authentication. Some will want to integrate with their Azure AD, some with their local Active directory, and some will have nothing and we will have to store their user/hash for them.

I've already done some (demo) applications, where you set some services in the ConfigureService, but here it will go farther:

How to have an application that will sometime use a local DB, sometime an external oAuth, ... ?

Is there a way to have some kind of wizard that will allow the admin to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible.

You can go with .Net Core + Ubuntu and provide two authentication providers: SSO login + local accounts (stored in database).

SSO login is compatible with Active Directory (Windows Server) and Azure Active Directory as well. It is also compatible with Facebook and Google. You can have multiple SSO login providers in parallel if you want.

Comment: I taught that SSO was refering to an approach than a technology. How do you configure it in the startup?

Comment: Google for "ASP.NET Core + SAML2"

Comment: The answers seems to point out that SAML2 is outdated: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp